# Does python webkit have a WebVeiw class

Tags: python, browser

When I try to run this from the terminal, it says;

> Gtk-Message: 17:53:10.044: Failed to load module
>   "canberra-gtk-module"Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "browser4.py", line 4, in 
>       view = webkit.WebView()  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebView'

here is my code:

```
import gtk 
import webkit 
view = webkit.WebView() 
sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow() 
sw.add(view) 
win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
win.add(sw) 
win.show_all() 
view.open("http://www.google.com") 
gtk.main()
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `__init__.pyc` file from the `webkit` folder. If you are on unix based OS follow the commands below. For windows, do the equivalent commands.

```sh
$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit
__init__.pyc

$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit/
```

This should solve your problem. [Here's](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pywebkitgtk/+bug/688732) a thread that discusses some possible solutions.

Comment: I tried it and it said that there was no such directory as /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-ackages/webkit __init__.pyc

Comment: The exact dir will not apply to you. you will have to manually locate yours.